# Error en autenticacion con firebase y angular 7

Tags: firebase, autenticación, angular7

Estoy haciendo un login con angular 7 y firebase, estoy usando angular/angularfire2. Hago el formulario, configuro todo, hago las importaciones necesarias. Todos los elementos visualizan sin ningun problema en el navegador( todavia no le di funcionalidad al boton para iniciar sesion ), hasta que pongo una variable en el constructor:

```
constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {}
```

A partir de esto ya no se visualiza nada en el navegador y la consola me lanza este error:

en firefox:

```
ERROR Error: "[object Object]"
```

en Chrome:

```
vendor.js:47983 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: 
StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[LoginComponent -> AngularFireAuth]: 
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[LoginComponent -> AngularFireAuth]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for AngularFireAuth!
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[LoginComponent -> AngularFireAuth]: 
       StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[LoginComponent -> AngularFireAuth]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for AngularFireAuth!
```

Dejo algunos archivos por si son necesarios.

environment.ts:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  config : {
    apiKey: "AIlpSyC5FYtKiisQApqldxL_-8Vjtk0_01llALU",
    authDomain: "axxxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://axxxxxx.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "axxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "axxxxxxx.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "123456789101"
  }

};
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { environment } from "../environments/environment";
import { AngularFireModule } from "@angular/fire";
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from "@angular/fire/database";

import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { PrincipalComponent } from './principal/principal.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

export const rutas: Routes = [
  { path: '',          component: PrincipalComponent},
  { path: 'login',          component: LoginComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    PrincipalComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(rutas),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.config),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

login.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { auth } from 'firebase/app';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  email = '';
  pass = '';

  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {}

  loginGoogle() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }
  logout() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

Solo cuando pongo esa variable en el constructor aparece el problema. 
Gracias a todos de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola creo que estas olvidando.

`app.module`
    import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';

`LoginComponent`
    import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

[Firebase_Google_Auth](https://github.com/fredyadriano90/firebase-google-auth)

Comment: el error sale cuando escribo afAuth: AngularFireAuth en el constructor, para eso hice el import del AngularFireAuth. Puedo hacer ese import de tu respuesta, pero nunca lo uso dentro del archivo. y aun asi el error sigue

Comment: El import lo estas haciendo en `app.module`?. Ahí es donde recomiendo el import.

Comment: Ni así se soluciona, recién hice la prueba. El error de Chrome marca con angularFireAuth.

Comment: Creo que en el `LoginComponent`, estabamos usando el `AngularFireAuth` del lugar incorrecto.

Comment: @VíctorHugoTirado probaste con los dos import que te pues?

Comment: Probé con todos los que usan en la documentación de github y no usan AngularFireAuthModule, ni siquiera es requerido, y en el constructor tampoco

Comment: Este ejemplo creo que te puede servir [firebase-google-auth](https://github.com/fredyadriano90/firebase-google-auth)

Comment: Solucionado con tu respuesta. Me falto importarlo al app.module.ts . Muchas gracias por la ayuda.